# Perl mojolicious datetime

Tags: perl, datetime, mojolicious, strftime

I am trying to convert an array to a date

```
% use Time::Piece;
% my $now = localtime;
<%= $now->strftime("%b %e %Y %X") %><br>
Feb 2 2018 09:13:04 AM <- or current date and time
<%= $now->strftime('%Y%m%d', gmtime()) %>
```

prints `20180202`

```
<%= $data->[1]->strftime('%Y%m%d', gmtime()) %>
```

Getting error

> can't locate object method `strftime` via package "Feb 2 2018 09:13:04AM

```
% for my $data (@$query_data){
  $data->[1]
  $data->[2] etc...
%}
```

The Data prints just fine, but when I try to I guess convert I get the error.

```
my $myquery = "select date1, name, id from table where id=5;";
```

Data returned from the query is Feb 5 2018 08:15AM,Mike,5

```
push(@query, @{$dbh->$myquery)});
$c->stash(query_data => \@query);
```

Comment: What is `$data->[1]`? It doesn't look like it's a `Time::Piece` - it looks more like it's a string containing a date

Comment: yes that is data from an array or hash.  I am not familiar with perl lingo.  But I received data from a query and I am looping over and displaying the data.  The output of data->[1] is Feb 5 2018 08:00AM

Comment: Your question really needs fleshing out with a [mcve] so we can see where `$data` is coming from.

Comment: And where does `$query_data` come from? And so on etc... eventually (hopefully) you'll get to the part of your code that generated "Feb 5 2018 08:00AM" and someone will be able to provide an answer for you.

Comment: There is a superfluous closing parenthesis in `push(@query, @{$dbh->$myquery)})`. You should always paste text copied directly from your live code to prevent simple errors like this.

Comment: What are all the percentage signs `%`? Are you also using [`Mojo::Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're doing a query to your database and one of the fields is being returned as a formatted date/time string. This isn't much use unless you're going to output it as is, so you need to parse it into a format that your code can use.

`Time::Piece` has a method for creating an object from a string called `strptime` which does the reverse of `strftime` that mimics the C function of the same name.

You need to go through each row in the results you get and parse that first field into the `Time::Piece` object the code in your template is expecting. I've not got any means of testing this, but I believe based on what code you've provided, that something like this should do the trick.

```
foreach my $row (@{$dbh->$myquery})
  {
  $row->[0]=Time::Piece->strptime($row->[0],"%b %e %Y %H:%M%p");
  push(@query, $row);
  }
$c->stash(query_data => \@query);
```

Comment: I was in the middle of trying that very code, but I am getting error parsing time.    sub strptime {
my $time = shift;
  my $string = shift;
   my $format = @_ ? shift(@_) : "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z";
    my @vals = _strptime($string, $format);
     return scalar $time->_mktime(\@vals, (ref($time) ? $time->[c_islocal] : 0));
484: }

Comment: It looks like that format isn't happy with the AM/PM at the end of the string, despite your example of output from `strftime` using it. I've found a format that should work and have updated the question accordingly.